# error when compiling java file script

Tags: shell-script, java, javascript

So I am trying to compile a .java file in my vim script but it keeps giving the error `"could not find or load main class name.java"` while I have put a main class in my .java file`, can someane help me with that? Thanks.

while i have made a file in my script

```java
public class $name {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
"text"
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: @jimmij in my script I wrote `javac $naam`      `java $naam`

Comment: this question answered before. kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: Im trying out what they are saying but can find it to work, must i use javac/java naam.java  or without .java?

Comment: What is the relevance of the [tag:shell-script] and [tag:javascript] tags to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$name` expands to the name of your class, the code must be in a file of exactly the same name plus extension .java. The javac commands wants the full file name, including .java, i.e.

```
javac CoolCode.java
```

if `$name` expands to `CoolCode`. Just "text" as the body will give you a compile error. If you get past this, run the code with

```
java CoolCode
```

Then read about classpath and package name and all the more in the javac and java manual: `man javac` and `man java`.

Comment: can i ask u another question?

Comment: No, not me specifically. Just ask another question.